# Google Cloud Storage not handling UTF-8 filenames

Tags: unicode, utf-8, google-cloud-storage

I am serving files from Google Cloud Storage and some of the filenames contain non-ASCII, UTF-8 encoded characters. For example, `volvía.mp3`.

If I request `volvía.mp3`, GCS throws an error.

If I percent encode the filename (í = %C3%AD) as `volv%C3%AD.mp3`, it still fails.

If I percent encode the filename using the "combining acute accent"  = %CC%81 as `volvi%CC%81a.mp3`, it succeeds.

Any ideas what is going on?

EDIT: The error it throws is an "Access Denied" error:
`Anonymous users does not have storage.objects.get access to object`. However, this seems to be the error one gets when requesting an object that's not found.

Comment: What is the error that GCS is returning?

Comment: @mike-schwartz An Access Denied error.

Comment: Phil - can you please email gs-team@google.com with details (the specific bucket and object names and exact time you made the request)? Please mention my name so it gets routed to me. Thanks.

Comment: Right, access denied can mean not found if you don't have permission to list the bucket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is due Mac OS's HFS+ file system, which enforces [canonical decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence#Normal_forms) (NFD) on filenames. This means it normalizes characters such as í into two code points (i + combining acute accent) rather than the single code point that is used in "composed" forms, ie., NFC).

GCS treats these two different forms as distinct filenames, despite that fact that they appear identical.

One solution is to convert NFD filenames to the more common NFC forms (using a utility such as `convmv`) before uploading to GCS. However, this can't be done on Mac OS because the file system itself enforces NFD.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to reproduce your issue. I uploaded an object named `volvía.mp3` and was able to retrieve it as both `http://storage.googleapis.com/bucketname/volvía.mp3` and `http://storage.googleapis.com/bucketname/volv%C3%ADa.mp3`

I suspect that you actually created an object with the "combining acute accent" character instead. How did you upload your object?

Comment: The files were uploaded using `gsutil -m cp`.

Comment: That is a reasonable suspicion, however, this is where things get a bit murky. If I receive a text in UTF-8 and it includes the word _volvía_ and I extract that word, store it in sqlite, retrieve it, write it out as a filename, and upload the file -- does it matter if that original text used a combining accent? Bc that's the only way I can see this could have happened? I have never encountered the idea of needing to normalize the way diacritics are encoded.

Comment: Furthermore, if I upload the same file to my own server, it is served just fine.